# Sorting UITableView results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

SO here's my setup. I have an object called RadioStations where I have several strings like callsign, frequency declared and an NSMutableArray called amStationInfo. On my viewcontroller, I access an SQLite database which populates the an array like so...

RadioStations.h

```
@interface RadioStations : NSObject {

    NSString *format;
    NSString *city;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *format;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *city;
```

ViewController.m

```
NSMutableArray* amStationInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *cityField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10)];
        NSString *formatField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
        RadioStations *amStationClass = [[RadioStations alloc] init];            
                [amStationClass setCity:cityField];
                [amStationClass setFormat:formatField];
                [amStationInfo addObject:amStationClass];
    }
[tabView reloadData];
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

and then I populate a UITableView

```
NSString *cityValue = [(RadioStations *)[amStationInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] city];
NSString *formatValue = [(RadioStations *)[amStationInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] format];
cityLabel.text = cityValue;
formatLabel.text = formatValue;
```

I would like to be able to sort the UITable results based on city (alphabetical) or format (numeric) and both, city, and then format. I know format is NSString, let's just say I got the doubleValue of it already.  I'd like to have results like so....

City (alphabetical)
1) Los Angeles - 5.0
2) San Francisco - 3.0
3) San Jose - 10.0
4) San Jose - 2.0
5) San Jose - 4.0

Format (numeric)
1) San Jose - 2.0
2) San Francisco - 3.0
3) San Jose - 4.0
4) Los Angeles - 5.0
5) San Jose - 10.0

Both (city then format)
1) Los Angeles - 5.0
2) San Francisco - 3.0
3) San Jose - 2.0
4) San Jose - 4.0
5) San Jose - 10

I have a method to sort the format like so... in RadioStations.m

```
- (NSComparisonResult)sortByFormat:(id)anObject
{
    if (self.format < anObject.format) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (self.format > anObject.format) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

but I get a "property 'format' not found on object of type '_strong id' and it was highlighting anObject.format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you passing in a RadioStation instead of an id?  Maybe I am missing something, but I think that is all you need to do...

```
    - (NSComparisonResult)sortByFormat:(RadioStation *)anObject
{
if (self.format < anObject.format) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
} else if (self.format > anObject.format) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}
return NSOrderedSame;
```

}

Comment: That worked, however now when I call for it I get this: Incompatible types assigning to 'NSMutableArray * _strong from 'NSArray *' when I call amStationInfo = [amStationInfo sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortByFormat:)];

Comment: try amStationInfo = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray  [amStationInfo sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortByFormat:)]];  (or something similar - my syntax might be off on this one)